# Not able to run Junit test with H2 database SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, h2, junit5

I have a strange problem with my unit test..
My goal is to run test on a H2 database and not on my Mysql database..

Actually the strange thing is that when i click on maven test it runs the app, trying to connect to mysql.. crash and the start with the h2 database and unit test fail..

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest

// @ActiveProfiles("test") // Without this it runs on my mysql and works.. , 
// with this annotation the behaviour is described above

@Transactional
class BelugaprojectsApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private ICheckConfigService iCheckConfigService;

    @Autowired
    private CheckConfigJpaRepository checkConfigJpaRepository;

    @Test 
    void getAllCheckConfigDeploiement() {
        assertThat(iCheckConfigService.getAllCheckConfigDeploiement(
                Integer.parseInt(AppConstants.DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER), 
                Integer.parseInt(AppConstants.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE),
                "id").getTotalElements() > 0);
    }
}
```

Properties

```
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    username: root
    password:
  jpa:
    open-in-view: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
```

Running with the test profile activated it throws

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "HISTORIQUEDEPLOIEMENT" non trouvée
Table "HISTORIQUEDEPLOIEMENT" not found; SQL statement:
alter table historiquedeploiement add constraint FK134pkswiisobg18okjr9pegt7 foreign key (id_namespace) references namespace (id) [42102-200]
Table "CHECKCONFIGDEPLOIEMENT" non trouvée
Table "CHECKCONFIGDEPLOIEMENT" not found; SQL statement:
```

Dependencies

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What's the name of the properties file and where is it located?

Comment: application-test.yaml located in test/resources

Comment: Try using only application.yaml instead.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this h2 file cofiguration :

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.repository")
    public class DatabaseConfig {
       @Autowired
       private DataSource dataSource;
       @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new 
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.example.model" });
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("entityManager");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }
    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        return properties;
    }    
}
```

and modify the application.properties like this :

## Datasource configuration

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:MyProjectName;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.application.admin.enabled=true
```

add this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
</dependency>
```

it work it for me

Comment: Sry, but this should not be at all necessary to do this..
I will wait a better solution

Comment: you didn't add the h2 dependency, it won't work in your project

Comment: Yes it was added sry